# How to get information about character spacing and word spacing from pdf file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, character-spacing

Used Pymupdf faced the problem of getting information about the text in the pdf file
I asked in the library's discord channel about the possibility of obtaining information about intervals, but they told me that the library does not know how to work with them
Perhaps there are other libraries that can do this?

I tried to look in other libraries but did not find it. Maybe I missed something....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: By *character spacing and word spacing* do you mean the values of the PDF text state parameters of that name or do you mean actual distances between characters and words?

Comment: @mkl 
im sorry i meant those parameters:
line spacing, paragraph spacing, character spacing

Comment: As per PyMuPDF: Before anyone gets a wrong impression: You **_can_** extract text with all desired metadata detail: text position (bbox), font properties, writing direction, etc. All this down to **_each single character_**. **_And all this works for PDF, XPS, EPUB_** and a handful more document types.
**Therefore** PDF-specific constructs like word and character spacing are not returned.

Comment: @user377394 - **_Line spacing_** is available in PyMuPDF, because it is a font property, which can be extracted in PyMuPDF. Also inter-line distance is can easily computed from the  line boundary boxes. **_Paragraph spacing_** is not even a PDF concept. But paragraph boundary boxes are available in PyMuPDF.

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

Usually, the information you're looking for is hidden behind layers of abstraction. A PDF library might typically allow you to extract text (and it uses information about word and character spacing to do so), but it does not make this information available to the outside world.

You can use `borb` to get access to this (low level) information.
The key concept here is `EventListener`. This is an interface. Classes implementing this interface get notified whenever a rendering event has finished.

Rendering events may include:

- text being rendered
- images being rendered
- switching to a new page
  and so on

There is a class that extracts text. So I would recommend you check out its code.
Looking at [line 62](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb/blob/3fdecff319ba0d08e419322e8fbde3f93bb4fa67/borb/toolkit/text/simple_text_extraction.py#L62), we see that any event that is "render a piece of text" gets redirected to its own separate method.

The method `_render_text` stores the `TextRenderInfo` objects until a page has finished rendering (at which point it will use the `TextRenderInfo` objects to determine the text that was on the page).

You can see the "end of page" logic in action on [line 87](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb/blob/3fdecff319ba0d08e419322e8fbde3f93bb4fa67/borb/toolkit/text/simple_text_extraction.py#L87).

Here you see that `TextRenderInfo` has all kinds of attributes related to position. You can use `get_baseline` to access it.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by pdfminer.six and pymupdf by getting line  and character position
thx all of you